Analog of Lower bound of matrix operator norm in the integral operator setting
For symmetric matrices $A = (a_{ij})_{1 \le i,j \le p}$, we have the following result about the operator norm:
$$
\|A\| \ge \max_{1\le i \le p}\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^p a^2_{ij}}.
$$
We can prove this as follows:
$$
\|A\| = \sup_{\|u\|_2=1} \|Au\|_2 \ge \max_{1 \le i \le p} \|A e_i \|_2
= \max_{1\le i \le p}\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^p a^2_{ij}},
$$
where $e_i$ is the $i$-th canonical basis vector.
My question is, does there exist an analogous result for integral operators (covariance operators) with symmetric kernels on a compact domain? Let $L_k$ be an integral operator with kernel $k$ on $E \times E $ where $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact, and $k(x,y) = k(y,x)$ and so that
$$
L_k f(x) = \int_E k(x,y) f(y) dy.
$$
Can we show something like
$$
\|L_k \| \ge \sup_{x \in E} \sqrt{\int_E k^2(x,y)dy}
$$

No, this is not true. For example, consider $E = [0, 1]$, $k(x, y) = xy$. Then, since
$$\|L_k\| = |x\rangle \langle y|$$
We have $L_k = \|x\|_2 \|y\|_2 = \frac{1}{3}$. But,
$$\sup_{x \in [0, 1]} \sqrt{\int_0^1 k^2(x, y) \, dy} = \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} x \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} > \|L_k\|$$
As a general intuition, if you choose $k(x, y) = f(x)f(y)$, then the same argument shows $\|L_k\| = \|f\|_2^2$ but the RHS is $\|f\|_\infty\|f\|_2$, so your inequality will never hold as long as there exists some $f$ with $\|f\|_2 < \|f\|_\infty$. So the inequality basically can only hold when we’re working with sequence spaces, i.e., the case with matrices.

In fact, following this argument further, you can see that if $E$ is a probability space, it is actually the opposite inequality that is true.

could you please define the notation $|x\rangle$?

@WeakLearner https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation

@WeakLearner By $|x\rangle\langle y|$, I just meant the rank-one operator that is given by inner product with the function $y$, then multiplying the resulting scalar with the function $x$. Different people use different notations for this, for example some use the notation $x \otimes y$ (or $y \otimes x$, depending on the convention used).
